# Insert append data into mysql database using python

Tags: python, database, image-processing, append, mysql-python

I have face some issue to mu code when I want to insert student matrix number into mysql database table. In my code I have use append() function to collect student's matrix number. When I pass the matrix_num.append() to database. The result in the database show 0 in Matrix_Number's column and it also show student's matrix number in one row only. The database should store 3 student's matrix due to   the output have 3 matrix number (19876, 23456, 13791846). I have attach my code, output and database result. Anyone have idea? Thank you.

**Code:**

```
number = (int(pred[0]))
num_list_matrix.append(number)       //matrix number of each student
matrix_num.append(num_list_matrix)   //matrix number collected from 3 students 


print("Number: ", number)
print ("Matrix number: ", num_list_matrix)
print("Students mtrix num: ", matrix_num) 

`StudentMarks = "INSERT INTO students_mark (Matrix_Number) VALUES (%s)"
matrixnumber = ["matrix_num"]
mycursor.execute(StudentMarks, matrixnumber)

mysqlconnect.commit()
print("Record Saved Successfully...!")


mycursor.close()
mysqlconnect.close()
print("MySQL connection is closed")`
```

**Output:**

[image: Output:]

**Database output:**
[image: Database output]

Comment: Hmmm... ```matrixnumber=(matrix_num)```. Try this?

Comment: I have try this. got error too